# Replace values in several data.table's columns that meet a condition

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table("cat" = c(0,5,NA,0,0,0),
                  "horse" = c(0,4,2,1,1,3),
                  "fox" = c(2,2,NA,NA,7,0))
```

I wish to replace values of 'cat' and 'fox' that are equal to '0' or '2' with '-99'

I can do it one at a time but how to do them both?

```
dat[fox == 0 | fox == 2, fox := -99]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is using a `for(...) set(...)`-approach, which is in this case both fast and memory efficient:

```
cols <- c('fox', 'cat')

# option 1
for (j in cols) d[get(j) %in% c(0, 2), (j) := -99]

# option 2 (thx to @Cole for highlighting)
for (j in cols) set(d, which(d[[j]] %in% c(0, 2)), j, value = -99)

# option 3 (thx to @Frank for highlighting)
for (j in cols) d[.(c(0,2)), on = j, (j) := -99]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > d
>    cat horse fox
> 1: -99     0 -99
> 2:   5     4 -99
> 3:  NA     2  NA
> 4: -99     1  NA
> 5: -99     1   7
> 6: -99     3 -99
> ```

---

```
d  <- data.table("cat"   = c(0,5,NA,0,0,0),
                 "horse" = c(0,4,2,1,1,3),
                 "fox"   = c(2,2,NA,NA,7,0))
```

Comment: You could change this to ```set``` very quickly using ```which(d[["j"]] %in% c(0, 2))```. +1

Comment: @Cole In cases like this, I favor the first option. Mostly for readability. Anyway, added the `set` alternative as well. Note that using `:=` also falls under [tag:data.table]'s `for() set()`-approach.

Comment: Another: `for (cc in cols) d[.(c(0,2)), on=cc, (cc) := -99]` instead of `get` and `%in%`.

Comment: @Frank Thx for bringing that option to my attention (again). My brain is apparently not trained for solving this kind of problems with joins :-/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not-so-elegant way of doing this:

```
> data
   cat horse fox
1:   0     0   2
2:   5     4   2
3:  NA     2  NA
4:   0     1  NA
5:   0     1   7
6:   0     3   0

> data[, c('fox', 'cat') := list(ifelse(cat %in% c(0,2) | fox %in% c(0,2), 99, cat ), ifelse(cat %in% c(0,2) | fox %in% c(0,2), 99, cat ))]
> data
   cat horse fox
1:  99     0  99
2:  99     4  99
3:  NA     2  NA
4:  99     1  99
5:  99     1  99
6:  99     3  99
```

I'm calling `(c('cat', 'fox'))` explicitly, but you could save them as `mycols` and assign using `:=` operator: `data[, mycols := ...]`

Similarly, I'm passing a list explicitly based on the conditions - this could be better done using a function instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, this would work as well:

```
cols = c("cat", "fox")
data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function (x) fifelse(x %in% c(0, 2), -99, x)), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: I thought of this but the OP wants it to be based on two columns instead of just one.

Comment: @Gautam if that is the case, your approach would be simplified by including it in ```i``` arg: ```data[fox %in% c(0, 2) | cat %in% c(0, 2), c("cat", "fox") := -99]```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that!